# Intellij how to ignore duplicated classes from "out" directory when using gradle and tools like lombok, google protobuf and swagger

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

My project has many modules and we're using gradle with few code generators. Example configuration:

```
sourceSets {
...
    swagger {
        compileClasspath = configurations.swaggerCompile
        java {
            srcDir file("${project.buildDir.path}/build/generated/source/swagger/")
        }
    }
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/...'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/...'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    generatedSourcesDir = 'build/generated/source'
}

protobuf {
    ...
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "${buildDir}/generated-src/..."
}
```

Project doesn't compile with Intellij, because its generating classes both in specified directories and in /out/ directory generated by Intellij.

Same duplicated classes are for example generated in:

\out\production\classes\generated\ - Intellij
\build\generated-src..\ - Gradle

It gives me hundreds of error messages like: Error:(30, 14) java: duplicate class: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.YourClass I've tried everything I could find here and on Intellij forums. Nothing worked for me.

I even tried to exclude "out" directory in File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Excludes but it doesn't work either.

The only way is to build project, manually delete all "out" dirs and then disable annotation processors. But it's not the best way to make it working.

Comment: Switch on the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle** option, this should fix build errors.

Comment: Another option to try is to disable **Create Separate modules per source set** in Gradle settings.